# Django all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: django

I'm working on a simple app. My app allows a user to create an account and add boards.

I'm trying to  retrieve all the boards the user created and display on a template without getting this error.

```
all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Traceback:
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\o\mysite\pet\views.py" in Display
69.     board = Board.objects.all(user=request.user)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Parts of my views.py ( Problem is here )**

```
def Display(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pet.views.LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.all(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'board':board})
```

My edit.html

```
{% if board %}
<ul>           
    <li>Name: {{ board.name }}</li>

</ul>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all() is all. If you want to query based on value use filter()

```
def Display(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pet.views.LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'board':board})

{% if board %} 
<ul>  
    {% for b in board %}         
    <li>Name: {{ b.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: your view is good now. It's good to see codes that are arrange, simple, and small

Comment: I tried your answer before but it doesn't display all the boards

Comment: Do you have data in board that have user?

Comment: Yep , I also got proof . Posted on top

Comment: forgot to use forloop in template

Comment: this is (user=request.user) associated with Board module field called user?

Answer (score 2):

To get all with where `user` is `request.user`, you should use the `filter` method. So instead:

```
board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Hope this fixes it!

Comment: Yeah , I tried this before . It doesn't display all the boards .